# i want to plot graph on graph widget of my application but on my output window labels are added to graph widget but no data is plotted

Tags: dataframe, pyqtgraph

I want to plot a line graph of wind speed with respect to time for this i write the code:

```
    hour = self.df.iloc[:, 1]
    Windspeed = self.df.iloc[:, 5]
    self.Graph_Widget.setBackground('w')  # Set background color
    styles = {'color': 'r', 'font-size': '50px'}
    self.Graph_Widget.setLabel('left', 'Wind Speed (m/s)', **styles)  # Set Ylabel
    self.Graph_Widget.setLabel('bottom', 'Minutes (H)', **styles)  # Set xlabel
    self.Graph_Widget.plot(hour, Windspeed, color='blue') # plot graph
    self.Graph_Widget.showGrid(x=True, y=True)  # Show Grid lines
    self.Graph_Widget.setXRange(0, 20, padding=0)  # X-axis range
    self.Graph_Widget.setYRange(0, 10, padding=0)  # Y-axis range
```

but i got error:
isfinite = np.isfinite(x) & np.isfinite(y)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
printExc('Ignored exception:')

i add this to the code:
hour.astype(float)
Windspeed.astype(float)
and got another error that is:
return arr.astype(dtype, copy=true) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ valueerror: could not convert string to float: '00:00:00'

Comment: From the errors you get, the problem lies in the conversion from str to float. I suggest you read the documentation of dataframe about the conversion of their standards.